# Query complex JSON on Couchbase Server Query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm running Queries on Couchbase Server Query on Complex JSON,

```
{
    "fname": "saksham",
    "lname": "handu",
    "dateOfBirth": {
        "day": 30,
        "month": 11,
        "year": 1996
  }
}
```

I'm running

```
`SELECT * from `bucket-name` where fname="saksham";
```

But it's not showing above JSON as a result. If I remove `dateOfBirth` from JSON, then fire the same query, it's showing the JSON then. Can someone help here?

Moreover, how to write Queries on `year` in `dateOfBirth`?

Comment: Why did you tag your Couchbase question with CouchDB and CouchApp, which are completely unrelated?

Comment: What index(es) have you created?

Comment: I have run this query with a primary index (the bare minimum required, but not recommended for production) and it's working fine. To answer the second part of your question: `select * from bucketname where dateOfBirth.year=1996;` I highly recommend you check out some N1QL documentation, starting with this interactive tutorial: https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/tutorial/